# Multiple Columns but only one join

Tags: sql, database-design

I have searched through quite a few answers on this but I can't seem anything specific to this situation. Apologies if I have over looked this.

We have a calendar system we are re-coding to log events, holidays, absent days, MOT's, Inspections etc

Initially our calendar focused around people, so we had a join from the person table to the calendarDay, but now other tables from the database are required to have days assigned to them.

My plan was to have a junction table for each of the three tables needing joined - Person, Job and Vehicle, or, have an ID column in the Assignment junction table that has a column for Person_ID, Job_ID and Vehicle_ID fk's:

### CalendarDayAssignment

`ID      CalendarDayID   PersonID   JobID   VehicleID`

so this table would contain a CalendarDay_ID and either a Person_ID, Job_ID or Vehicle_ID depending on which table has a day assigned to it, leaving two columns having a NULL. (These could be moved directly to the CalendarDay table actually, as days will not be shared)

My preference would be the later shown above as I would only need one table, rather than 3 (potentially more if more objects need days assigned to them), and the referential data integrity is intact also.

I know this may be subjective, but is this a reasonable way of accomplishing this? It seems easier to include more objects should the time come.

Just as a note to the above, we will be pulling different data from the Person, Job and Vehicle tables, so I can't see how to implement a one size fits all solutions that doesn't end up with redundant data from a coding POV. The Junction table will likely have only 10,000 rows per year added.

Comment: You could have a table with CalanderDayID, CalanderDayAssociationID, AssociationID  (where CalanderDayAssociationID is an ID to a lookup table for what table the CalanderID is associated to so this table would have PersonID, JobID, etc, and you could add as many as needed.  Then the CalanderDayAssociaionID is the ID in that table for the AssociasionID  (so PersonID would be in this colmn if the AssociationID is the PErsonID)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't realise I could use the value from a database column as a table join assignment.